# Python и bash команды

Tags: python-3.x

Как перехватить результат выполнения bash команды из скрипта Python и записать ее в переменную?

Я использую вот такую конструкцию:

```
import subprocess

path = subprocess.Popen('pwd', shell=['sh'], encoding='utf-8', stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

и все даже работает, но если отпринтить переменную path то получаю вот что:

```
('/home/pi\n', None)
```

Вопрос такой: Как убрать все лишнее типа "\n" и None, что бы получилась строка с абсолютным путем, вот такая
**('/home/pi/')**

---

strip() - пробовал не помогает

Comment: Документацию читали? https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Comment: «strip() - пробовал не помогает» — как пробовали и почему не помогает? Какое-нибудь `path[0].rstrip('\n')` должно отлично работать

Comment: Небось результат после `strip` никуда не сохранялся потом )

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Спасибо большое! Проблему решил вот так: path = subprocess.Popen('pwd', shell=['sh'], encoding='utf-8', stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]